# MySQL Limit Number Of Rows Returned By Union All Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query a dozen tables and return a UNION ALL of all of these tables. All of these tables have the same column names. The number of rows returned by this query should be a maximum of 100.

```
`SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2 LIMIT 100;`
```

The above query causes 100 rows from table2 to be combined with all rows from table1. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM ( 
  SELECT column1, column2 
  FROM table1 
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT column1, column2 
  FROM table2
) as resutl_table 
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Using:

SELECT column1, column2 FROM ( SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2) DerivedTableName LIMIT 100;

works. Placing a name for the derived table after the derived table definition is able to produce results.

Comment: The example in the answer needs an alias for the sub_query.

Answer (score 2):

You want the limit to apply to all tables, so you "wrap" a query around your base query. The wrapped query can then apply a row count limit to all tables taken as a single result set.

```
SELECT * FROM ( <your existing query> ) LIMIT 100;
```

You could also apply an order as well if desired.

```
SELECT * FROM ( <your existing query> ) ORDER BY column1 LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2 ) as t 
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM  (
            SELECT column1, column2 
            FROM table1 
              UNION ALL 
            SELECT column1, column2 
            FROM table2 
            ) as result_set LIMIT 100
```